# Warning is not disappering for M2ePro module update

Tags: magento2

I am using M2ePro extension. It had version 1.3.4 and it was showing warning on admin dashboard that:

> Important: It is recommended to update to the version 1.3.5. Please
>   refer to https://docs.m2epro.com/ for Installation/Upgrade
>   instructions

So I updated it to version 1.4 which is latest version but still its showing above warning. I do not understand why this warning is still present when I upgraded to latest version. Please let me know from where this warning is coming and how to remove this?

Thanks